# Do we need to distribute the root certificate to client?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

After running below commands to create the root certificate, server certificate and Server private key:

Step 1) Create certificate authority key(private key)

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca-key.pem 4096
```

Step 2) Create Certificate authority(root certificate) with the input(ca-key.pem)

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -out ca.pem
```

Step 3) Create a private key for web server

```
$ openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 4096
```

Step 4) Create Certificate signing request(CSR) by entering user identification. This will create public key in-turn.

```
$ openssl req -subj "/CN=dockerbuild.harebrained-apps.com" -sha256 -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr
```

Step 5) Add the configuration

```
$ echo subjectAltName = IP:40.xx.xx.164,IP:10.0.0.4,IP:127.0.0.1,DNS:dockerbuildsys.westus.cloudapp.azure.com,DNS:dockerbuild.harebrained-apps.com > extfile.cnf
```

Step 6) Create server certificate

```
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
```

---

We deployed as shown below:

[image]

---

Root certificate is a self-signed certificate

---

Before a client performs a TLS handshake,

Do we need to manually supply  `ca.pem` to every client? to add it in trusted list before accessing the server from a browser(or any other client)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What is the client software that will be used to access your server? Forcing users to trust your ca for browsing is a mistake and a bad design.

Comment: @JamesKPolk  One client is browser and other client is native client(internal). Browser does not say... any untrusted site issue

Comment: Why can't you just get a real certificate from a trusted CA?

Comment: @JamesKPolk does real root certificate from trusted CA, stops browser accessing server unless we manually supply the certificate to all clients?

Comment: You don't distribute a real CA's root certificate, it's already installed in platforms/browsers and thus pre-trusted. And if you use Let's Encrypt it's free.